# Authorize.net Accept.js partial refunds not working / not enabled on Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, authorize.net

We are using Authorize.net Acceptjs as a payment method and it does not allow us to create partial refunds. Any help to resolve this issue for Magento 2.3.3 would be greatly appreciated.